# jQuery - Add click event to a dynamically created element

Tags: jquery

I have dynamically created this elements clicking the #btnAgregar button:

```
var items = 0

$("#btnAgregar").click(function(){

  items = items + 1

  var item_name =  $("#itemLista").val();

  var $div_task = $("<div/>", { class: "div_task" }),
      $div_task_nombre = $("<div/>", { class: "div_task_nombre" }),
      $div_task_edicion = $("<div/>", { class: "div_task_edicion" }),
      $div_task_nombre_item = $("<p/>", {class: "item task_undone", text: item_name}),
      $div_task_edicion_btnEliminar = $("<button/>", {class: "btn btn-danger", type: "button", id: items}),
      $div_task_edicion_btnEliminar_span = $("<span/>", {class:"glyphicon glyphicon-minus"});

  $div_task.append(
                  $div_task_nombre.append(
                                          $div_task_nombre_item
                                        ), 
                  $div_task_edicion.append(
                                            $div_task_edicion_btnEliminar.append($div_task_edicion_btnEliminar_span)
                                          )
                  ).appendTo("#container_lista");

});
```

This code works fine.

I need to add a click event to the element "#btnEliminar"+items

If I do this, the code doesn't work:

```
$('body').on('click', '#'+items, function() {
  //Do something
});
```

But if I just add the id "#1" (first element created) it works fine.

Ej:

```
$('body').on('click', '#1', function() {
  //Do something
});
```

Can you help me?

Comment: I have to use an ID to select a specific element.

I add x elements each one must have an id  to identify it and make something with it.

In the example that I've posted above, when I use the ID "#1" the code works fine because I've used it manually, but when I use a variable as an ID, "#"+items, it does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can add it right to the object as you create it, or add another class that is specific to that type of button.

Using `class = btnEliminar`:

```
$('body').on('click', '.btnEliminar', function() {
  alert(this.id.replace('btnEliminar','');
});
```

you only need to run this code once within your page load code

Comment: I have to use an ID to select a specific element.

If I add x elements each one must have an id  to identify it and make something with it.

In the example that I've posted above, when I use the ID "#1" the code works fine because I've used it manually, but when I use a variable as an ID, "#"+items, it does not.

Comment: My code expects you to add that id, but also add a common class as well. The alert is parsing the ID. The reason to use class is it will cover many elements with different ID's

Comment: The alert dialog is an example. I've just updated it on the code.

When I use the ID "#1" the code works fine because I've used it manually, but when I use a variable as an ID, "#"+items, it does not. I don't understand why.

Comment: I used your recommendation and it worked, thank you very much. But I still don't understand why I can't access the ID using the variable this way: "#" + items

Comment: How can I access to an ID using a variable? I've used "#"+variable, but I doesn't work.

Comment: not clear what you are trying to do. I already showed you how to access id of element clicked `this.id`

Comment: I'm just learning, sorry if I can't explain myself properly.  How can I assing a variable as an ID to a selector for using it later, for example to remove it. I have this variable: items = 5; I have a selector using that variable as an ID. I need to remove it.

Comment: Maybe you need to create another question with whatever code you are referring to

Answer (score 0):

You want to bind the event to the `document` or `'body'` or something similar. If you want match dynamically-numbered elements, you can use a selector like `div[id^="example"]` to match any ID that starts with `example` like `<div id="example1">` and `<div id="example2">`.

```
$(document).on('click', 'div[id^="example"]', function() {
    console.log('element clicked');
});
```

Comment: How can I access to an ID using a variable? I've used "#"+variable, but I doesn't work.